# How to index Postgresql query with multi-column and order

Tags: postgresql

This query take 2s to done:

```sql
explain analyze select
    *
from
    "MdChapters" as "MdChapter" 
where
    ("MdChapter"."countryCode" = 'gb' AND "MdChapter"."deletedAt" is  null)
order by
    "MdChapter"."id" desc 
limit 100;
```

```sql
Limit  (cost=56.35..56.38 rows=13 width=2656) (actual time=1854.038..1854.409 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=56.35..56.38 rows=13 width=2656) (actual time=1854.035..1854.163 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: id DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 150kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "MdChapters" "MdChapter"  (cost=4.56..56.10 rows=13 width=2656) (actual time=49.818..1355.082 rows=327179 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((("countryCode")::text = 'gb'::text) AND ("deletedAt" IS NULL))
              Heap Blocks: exact=47298
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test  (cost=0.00..4.55 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=42.630..42.632 rows=328948 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((("countryCode")::text = 'gb'::text) AND ("deletedAt" IS NULL))
Planning time: 0.200 ms
Execution time: 1854.567 ms
```

But this query just take < 0.1s:

```sql
select
    *
from
    "MdChapters" as "MdChapter" 
where
    ("MdChapter"."countryCode" = 'gb')
order by
    "MdChapter"."id" desc 
limit 100;
```

I have indexes on both colum `countryCode` and `deletedAt`

```sql
CREATE INDEX md_chapters_deleted_at_country_code ON public."MdChapters" USING btree ("deletedAt", "countryCode");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create [filtered/parial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html):

```
CREATE INDEX md_chapters_deleted_at_country_code2 ON public."MdChapters" 
USING btree ("countryCode", "id")
WHERE ("deletedAt" IS NULL);
```

Comment: Not work for me, this is Explain result: https://explain.depesz.com/s/gpgJ

Comment: Let's try adding id: `CREATE INDEX md_chapters_deleted_at_country_code2 ON public."MdChapters" 
USING btree ("countryCode", "id")
WHERE ("deletedAt" IS NULL);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, its work now :). Now it just takes 0.6ms https://explain.depesz.com/s/Zt7b

Comment: Can you explain why the index is work: ```CREATE INDEX md_chapters_deleted_at_country_code2 ON public."MdChapters" 
USING btree ("countryCode", "id", "deletedAt"). ```

But if I change index column order: ```("id", "countryCode", "deletedAt") or ("countryCode", "id", "createdAt") ``` , it won't work.

Comment: When you are creating covering index you should start with columns that are used for filtering i.e. country_coude, then deteledAt and finally id. I am not sure if PostgreSQL supports [index skip column scan](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/optimops.htm#51553).

Comment: I just have tried with order `("countryCode", "deletedAt", "id")` isn't work . Its strange.

Comment: @meotimdihia Please try adding `WHERE ("deletedAt" IS NULL)` to index from prev comment. I guess Postgresql does not store null in indexes.

Comment: @meotimdihia I would gladly discuss that matter further but I have to go out

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to continue to find out this problem :)

Comment: You should open a new question for the other problem.